# Tag for blacklisting - for

Tags: support, retag-request, blacklist

As a follow-up to https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6059/tag-for-removal-for and [as suggested by *slhck ♦*](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6059/tag-for-removal-for#comment16537_6059), am requesting for the [for](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/for) tag to be blacklisted.

Comment: Moderators can't do it, and given that it never was much used, I doubt *this* will become the ~10th or so blacklisted tag.

Comment: @DanielBeck: You can see that that was *precisely* what I asked about [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6059/tag-for-removal-for#comment16539_6059) before posting this request. I am confused... Should I delete this request now?

Comment: Your request is fine and I +1'd it. We really *should* start to blacklist useless tags more, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Oh well, I'll let it be then. I'm not waiting with bated breath anyway, since I already noted that it's not a high volume tag.